# Dot plot showing extra error bars and points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a dot plot with error bars in r from the following model:

I created a prediction data frame using the following code:

```
Abs_NT.Month = with(Abund_NT, 
                               expand.grid(
                    Month = factor(1:12), 
                    VegeType = unique(Abund_NT$VegeType), 
                    DistAgriLand = median(Abund_NT$DistAgriLand, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

But when I created the predictions and plot using the following code:

```
preds.Abs_NT.Month = predict(Abs_NT.final, newdata = Abs_NT.Month, se.fit = TRUE, 
                             type = "link")
preds.Abs_NT.Month.ci = Gam_ci(preds.Abs_NT.Month, Abs_NT.Month)
p.Abs_NT1 = ggplot(data = preds.Abs_NT.Month.ci) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Month, y = fit)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = Month, y = fit, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(label = xticks) +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Abundance") + 
  theme_customized()
p.Abs_NT1
```

I got the following plot with extra error bars and points:

[image]

However, when I used this code before with alterations for the data plotted it has worked fine. Does anyone know what I have done wrong and how to fix it?

Here's some sample data and other code needed to re-create the plot.

```
 preds.Abs_NT.Month.ci = structure(list(fit = c(21.6935978069045, 8.80250656329507, 19.6530792768087, 
10.5178640136739, 19.331951502499, 12.3804490066396, 19.2820274303385, 
6.31214503224883, 22.1160145236074, 14.7929596747438, 26.4172152928601, 
11.5287800062934, 6083718.0938543, 2468560.95180972, 5511478.32003321, 
2949613.06917569, 5421421.75733685, 3471953.44461311, 5407421.12987868, 
1770167.92168529, 6202179.96658866, 4148514.10245341, 7408401.87491935, 
3233112.7436146, 0.00611919613632483, 0.00248295670600778, 0.00554361926721337, 
0.00296681414524882, 0.00545303752723121, 0.00349220062074182, 
0.00543895525317997, 0.001780490900452, 0.00623834883583439, 
0.00417270673551857, 0.00745160499385129, 0.00325196708720192, 
3.38266797941513e-13, 1.37256887286685e-13, 3.06449131021545e-13, 
1.64004339564061e-13, 3.0144180743637e-13, 1.93047500918508e-13, 
3.00663344768247e-13, 9.84248489903166e-14, 3.44853513129464e-13, 
2.30665615993898e-13, 4.11921844739061e-13, 1.79767484011333e-13, 
30.4625385708598, 12.3606373682874, 27.5972059053941, 14.7693730220085, 
27.1462725333386, 17.3848482278622, 27.0761682570751, 8.86362710423911, 
31.0557036898997, 20.7725389158654, 37.0955268442071, 16.1889193642602, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), lwr = c(18.4178452668316, 7.27321118579896, 
16.24478889784, 8.72001880976386, 16.1728069925936, 10.6594081420019, 
16.3099853583417, 5.15659413716494, 18.795374696785, 12.5557992410152, 
21.3228679553751, 9.66773418026015, 412634.238435761, 169267.96955174, 
379124.654123528, 203173.32796686, 362560.308350271, 230529.17788665, 
365208.209732111, 122786.311052544, 421342.330538328, 282747.137091789, 
502252.850205695, 219660.297051045, 0.00077119081186168, 0.000310492558391415, 
0.000686528023158492, 0.00036876989358215, 0.000696724260707753, 
0.000454484695271143, 0.000690573195177653, 0.000218502919438299, 
0.000788547344905334, 0.000525401950858201, 0.000930909052411247, 
0.000410094818831386, 6.44195181938533e-16, 2.58622889490777e-16, 
5.73119597171667e-16, 3.07500583137761e-16, 5.80118568731678e-16, 
3.76634260845839e-16, 5.76371989126449e-16, 1.82396905066873e-16, 
6.57016290698435e-16, 4.37425515818948e-16, 7.80290625183578e-16, 
3.41575255996327e-16, 14.6736692257458, 6.00518969330933, 13.4174013785983, 
7.18383592225181, 12.923362548971, 8.34473892553187, 12.808636014629, 
4.32913704976547, 15.0122119615354, 9.99871593026379, 17.7918659860037, 
7.79773751079902, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), upr = c(25.5519676156282, 
10.6533578934352, 23.7764570219737, 12.6863789888008, 23.108193220022, 
14.3793647418417, 22.7956416670952, 7.72664550443932, 26.0233225620172, 
17.4287316751413, 32.7286772722055, 13.7480785006372, 89695964.120176, 
36000864.1264939, 80122442.4257535, 42821650.5823597, 81067378.8442661, 
52290390.4489174, 80064474.1729842, 25519900.7454725, 91296396.1840869, 
60867704.7459117, 109276469.646376, 47587197.8380054, 0.0485542109408958, 
0.0198557866760115, 0.0447639623484453, 0.0238685053352592, 0.0426791773307644, 
0.0268336102456296, 0.0428372176225054, 0.0145084919448299, 0.0493527705710914, 
0.0331393544926923, 0.0596475207116792, 0.0257874263478385, 1.77623847240326e-10, 
7.28452657254129e-11, 1.63859463831475e-10, 8.74711297174798e-11, 
1.56635502064982e-10, 9.894834720343e-11, 1.56840458232951e-10, 
5.31119258586916e-11, 1.81006083412807e-10, 1.21635854511667e-10, 
2.17456932964318e-10, 9.4609746287103e-11, 63.2402326851519, 
25.4422198054009, 56.7625393542698, 30.3646104705099, 57.0223198228677, 
36.2183826963216, 57.2362964056543, 18.1477011561134, 64.2448117669802, 
43.1553787526953, 77.3431023441726, 33.6098913075189, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Month = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), VegeType = structure(c(6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), A_Prec_Avg30Yr = c(303.92, 
303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 
303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 
303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 
303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 
303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 
303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 
303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 303.92, 
303.92, 303.92, 303.92, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), A_TAvg_Avg30Yr = c(21.08, 
21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 
21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 
21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 
21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 
21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 
21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 
21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, 21.08, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), DistPermWater = c(3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 
3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 
3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 
3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 
3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 
3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 
3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 3.085, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), DistAgriLand = c(594.37, 594.37, 
594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 
594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 
594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 
594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 
594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 
594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 
594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 594.37, 
594.37, 594.37, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), VarDayLength = c(1.04, 
1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 
1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 
1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 
1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 
1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 
1.04, 1.04, 1.04, 1.04, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), A_Psea_Avg30Yr = c(53.82, 
53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 
53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 
53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 
53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 
53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 
53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 
53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, 53.82, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
"21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", 
"32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", 
"43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", 
"54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "NA", "NA.1", "NA.2", 
"NA.3", "NA.4", "NA.5", "NA.6", "NA.7", "NA.8", "NA.9", "NA.10", 
"NA.11", "NA.12", "NA.13", "NA.14", "NA.15", "NA.16", "NA.17", 
"NA.18", "NA.19", "NA.20", "NA.21", "NA.22", "NA.23", "NA.24", 
"NA.25", "NA.26", "NA.27", "NA.28", "NA.29", "NA.30", "NA.31", 
"NA.32", "NA.33", "NA.34", "NA.35", "NA.36", "NA.37", "NA.38", 
"NA.39"), class = "data.frame")
}

xticks = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
```

For reference, here is the code I got from another (but very similar) question I asked and the code in the answer works fine ([Issue with fitted line on ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71325701/issue-with-fitted-line-on-ggplot))

Comment: Unfortunately your code is not running with the example data you provided. Also, as your issue is related to ggplot we don't need all steps of your analysis. It would be sufficient to include a snippet of the dataset `preds.Abs_NT.Month.ci` which you use for the plot. All other steps could be removed which would make your example more minimal and easier to focus on the main issue.

Comment: For some reason it won't let me edit the question and keep the title but the version with the correct code is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71585162/dotplot-eror-bars

Comment: Hi Dean. The issue is simply that you have multiple rows of data per month, i.e. one per `VegeType`. Hence you end up with multiple errorbars and points per month. You could see that clearly using `+ facet_wrap(~VegeType, scales = "free_y")`.

Comment: Thank you Sefan, how would I stop this from happening? I have tried using the levels() function but get the same result.